# Error while writing the tg bot. What to do?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

The following error is displayed in the line with StartReceiving:

> Severity Code Description Project File String Suppression Status
> Error CS0121 Ambiguous invocation of the following methods or properties:
> "Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClientPollingExtensions.StartReceiving(Telegram.Bot.ITelegramBotClient, System.Func<Telegram.Bot.ITelegramBotClient, Telegram.Bot.Types.Update, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, System.Func<Telegram.Bot.ITelegramBotClient, System.Exception, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, Telegram.Bot.Extensions.Polling.ReceiverOptions?, System.Threading.CancellationToken)" и "Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClientExtensions.StartReceiving(Telegram.Bot.ITelegramBotClient, System.Func<Telegram.Bot.ITelegramBotClient, Telegram.Bot.Types.Update, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, System.Func<Telegram.Bot.ITelegramBotClient, System.Exception, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>, Telegram.Bot.Polling.ReceiverOptions?, System.Threading.CancellationToken)"

The whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using System.Threading;

namespace Telegram_bot_Secret
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var client = new TelegramBotClient("TOKEN");
            client.StartReceiving(Update, null);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        async static Task Update(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken tocen)
        {
            var message = update.Message;
            if (message.Text != null)
            {
                if (message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Hello"))
                {
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Hello?");
                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
     }
}
```

Not a single post on the Internet has helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the compiler dous not know which overload of StartReceiving you are trying to use.
Naming your parameters could help ex

```
StartReceiving(parameter1Name: xxx, paramter2Name: xxx)
```

especially when using null this can happen, null could be used for a lot of parameters.

side note

```
message.Text.ToLower().Contains("Hello")
```

wont work as intended, if you use ToLower check for lowercase ("hello")